# Intermittent WCF activation errors

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm running a WCF service locally on my dev box, and my tests check all is well with the service.

Usually, all is fine, but sometimes (5% of the time), I get the error

```
The requested service, 'net.tcp://csmattdev2:9000/Wcf/Service.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
```

The info in the event log looks like:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/11404313
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/Wcf/Service.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_okepeg2c, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_okepeg2c, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 14844
```

To fix, the only thing that works is to reset IIS, and rebuild the comms project.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using, and is this service hosted in a "Website" or a "Web Project" in Visual Studio?

Comment: .Net 3.5, and it's hosted in IIS as a web application, with bindings for both http and net.tcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing everything from the web root except for the following things.

1) the .svc you are using to expose the endpoint
2) the .config file
3) the bin files that contain your service code

Bascially, remove all the web application stuff from the web root

Comment: This worked - removing everything I didn't absolutely need seemed to solve the problem for me